# Rascal fetch methods without comments

Tags: parsing, comments, rascal

I'm looking for a way to avoid comments during parsing. Here's my issue.

First I fetch all methods from a M3 model, like so:

```
public set[loc] getMethodLocations(M3 model){
  locations = { <x,y> | <x,y> <- model@containment,
  x.scheme=="java+class",
  y.scheme=="java+method" ||
  y.scheme=="java+constructor" };
  set[loc] methodLocations = { a | a <- range(locations) };
  return methodLocations;
}
```

Then I want to iterate over the fetched locations, like so:

```
set[loc] AllMethodsAsLoc = getMethodLocations(model);

for( methodAsLoc <- AllMethodsAsLoc ) {
  MethodDec m = parse(#MethodDec, methodAsLoc);
};
```

My issue is that the parsing seems to fail with a ParseError when a fetched method has comments at the location. How can I not include comments when fetching or how can I ignore comments during the parsing?

I'm new at this and learning, so please excuse my ignorance.

Any help is appreciated.

Rob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excellent question. Because `MethodDec` is not a "start" non-terminal it does not accept whitespace or comments before and after the actual `MethodDec`. So either we should trim the whitespace off somehow, or we could make a new non-terminal which *can* accept the layout.

The latter solution is the better IMHO:

```
start syntax MyTop = MethodDec method;

start[MyTop] theTop = parse(start[MyTop], methodAsLoc);
MyTop t = theTop.top
MethodDec dec = t.method;

// or more directly
dec = parse(start[MyTop], methodAsLoc).top.method;
```

Comment: Thank you jurgnv. This was exactly the solustion I needed. Wonderful.

Comment: For the ones reading and or using this later. Bear in mind that this solution only works for methods. The code sample also fetches constructors, so I needed to add the following as well in order to also process constructors: `syntax MyMethod = MethodDec | ConstrDec;' and the solution to the problem by @jurgenv: `start syntax MyTop = MyMethod method;` Declare variable and use it with parsing like so: `MyMethod m = parse(#start[MyTop], method).top.method;`